# What is the equivalent of nocite with mathtools equation referencing?

Tags: equations, mathtools

In general, I use mathtools in a mode that puts equation numbers only if an equation is referenced. How can I reference an equation without actually showing the number in the document, so that a label is put next to the equation?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Ax = b \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

The equation above will be numbered since I am referencing it using \refeq{eq1}.
The equation below will not be numbered since I am never referencing it. I want something like nocite: referencing
the equation, so that a number appears next to the equation, but no mention of that in the text.

\begin{equation}
Ax = b \label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "so that a label is put next to the equation"? Do you mean a specific symbol, or are you using the term "label" in the TeX/LaTeX sense of `\label`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your question. This will both make it easier to help and help to clarify your question (again making it easier to help).

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking to `\tag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\refeq`, besides typesetting the reference, writes an `\MT@newlabel` entry in the `.aux` file, so defining a `\silentrefeq` that does this will suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}

\makeatletter
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\silentrefeq}[1]{
  \@bsphack
  \MH_if_boolean:nT {show_only_refs} {
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\MT@newlabel{#1}}
  }
  \@esphack
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\silentrefeq{eq2}

An equation:
\begin{equation}
Ax = b \label{eq1}
\end{equation}
The equation above will be numbered since I am referencing it using \refeq{eq1}.

The equation below will not be numbered since I am never referencing it. I want something 
like nocite: referencing the equation, so that a number appears next to the equation, but 
no mention of that in the text.
\begin{equation}
Ax = b \label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In case `showonlyrefs` is not active, the command will do nothing. The `\silenteqref` command can go almost anywhere, but the start of the document is a good place.

[image]

Note that I didn't change your text, so as to make sure that no `\refeq{eq2}` was added that would trigger numbering the second equation; the number appears just because of the `\silentrefeq` command after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: The second equation appears to be numbered just fine in the screenshot...

Comment: @Mico That's what the OP seems to want. I didn't change the text.

Comment: I guess I'm completely confused. Your text says "The equation below will not be numbered since ..." (I realize now you copied the text from the OP.) Should you maybe write, "The equation below will be numbered even though it's not referenced explicitly"?

Comment: @Mico I didn't change in any way the original text, so as to make the OP sure that the result was as intended.